# Angular JS -- Dynamic $scope values

Tags: angularjs-scope

I want something like this.

```
function(propName)
{
$scope.Propname=true;
}
```

propName will be passed dynamically whenever the use click some command Link.

Thanks,
Ravi Narayanan

Comment: Please, provide more info on the problem you are having and what is stopping you to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a dynamic property key by doing this:

```
$scope[propName] = true;
```